# Day or Night CHECK in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, getdate

I have a Time_Interval column that should only have the values ​​"day" or "night". It will be "day" if it is from 8AM to 8PM and "night" if it is from 8PM to 8AM.
use CHECK for value entry.

Maybe I need use a trigger that checks the time in the getdate?

I have this:

```
CREATE TABLE Calls (
  Time_Interval VARCHAR(10) CHECK (
     Time_Interval='day' 
     OR Time_Interval='night'
   )
)
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: *"..will be "day" if **it** is from 8AM to 8PM.."*  What is "it" in this context? Is the interval based on another column in the table? Also, using IN(...) is shorter than multiple OR conditions.

Comment: it = Time_Interval

Comment: NO NO NO NO NO! There is simply no good reason to store a time value as varchar.

Comment: @AlexandraDidenco - No. Based on your description "Time_Interval" is a **string**: day or night. So "It" must refer to a date. We're asking what is that date - another column in the table or the current date and time when the record is created? Because there's probably a better option ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this

```
CREATE TABLE Calls 
(
 Time_Interval VARCHAR(10) CHECK (case when cast(getdate() as time) BETWEEN '8:00:01' AND '20:00:00' then 'day' else 'night' end =Time_Interval)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a computed column. Assuming that you're storing some time-ish† value in your table, you can derive day/night like so:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Calls (
    ts time(0) not null,
    Time_Interval as 
        case when datepart(hour, ts) between 8 and 19 
        then 'day'
        else 'night'
    end
);
```

When I insert test data into the table, it appears correct to me.

```
insert into dbo.Calls (ts) values
    ('08:00'),
    ('07:59'),
    ('19:59'),
    ('20:00');
```

† any data type with a time component should work.